# Force code to pause executing until a function with a promise in it has concluded executing - javascript

Tags: javascript, function, asynchronous, promise, async-await

I am trying to use functions to keep my code clean.

I want to create a reusable function - getNumberOfCountriesDownloaded() - that calculates the number of countries that I have downloaded.

This function has a promise all in it and returns a value when the promise has finished executing.

The problem is that when I call this function (from another function), it immediately executes the next line....so the variable I am saving the result of getNumberOfCountriesDownloaded() is undefined.

It is possible to pause execution until the getNumberOfCountriesDownloaded() function has finished executing its code?

If not, whats the best way to write clean code and dry code with promises?

```
function getNumberOfCountriesDownloaded(countryCodes) {

  let CountriesDownloaded = countryCodes.map(countryCode => { return localStorage.getItem(countryCode) })

  Promise.allSettled(CountriesDownloaded).then(countries => {

     let countriesDownloaded = countries.filter(country => country.value !== null).length

     return countriesDownloaded

   })
}

async function dataForGraphs(countryData) {

let countriesDownloaded = await getNumberOfCountriesDownloaded()

console.log('countriesDownloaded - after promise', countriesDownloaded)

//run rest of code
}
```

Comment: `getNumberOfCountriesDownloaded` doesn't return anything for you to await.

Comment: It returns the countriesDownloaded variable.....

Comment: nah, you're returning that to the .then callback (which is necessary, but you need more than that.)

Comment: Agreed, you should be returning the `Promise` itself, e.g. `return Promise.allSettled(...)`

Comment: how should the code be written to return the countriesDownloaded variable?

Comment: @FoundingBox - Brilliant - that works. If you wanna post that as the answer, I would be happy to accept it

Comment: Sounds good, I will!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `getNumberOfCountriesDownloaded` needs to be a promise itself, in order for you to be able to `await` its results in other functions. You can do this by returning a `Promise`.

```
function getNumberOfCountriesDownloaded(countryCodes) {

  let CountriesDownloaded = countryCodes.map(countryCode => { return localStorage.getItem(countryCode) })

  return Promise.allSettled(CountriesDownloaded).then(countries => {

     let countriesDownloaded = countries.filter(country => country.value !== null).length

     return countriesDownloaded

   })
}
```